# A way to catch any change of an object with properties

Tags: c#, object, properties, element

I have a simple program that's supposed to capture any change of object A. When it does detect a change, it will write down the stringified object into file A.

Now the most obvious approach would be to use properties.

```
public static ClassA classA = new ClassA();
public static Action onLocalDataChange;
public class ClassA
{
    public string foo;
    public bool bar;
}
public static ClassA ClassA
{
    get { 
        return classA ; 
    }
    set
    {
        classA = value;
        onClassAChange.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Now, I'll use this property as such:

```
ClassA.foo = "test";
```

It won't work because the setter only works for the changes of the class as whole, and not the element inside of it.

Is there a way to make properties work in a way that can capture any change of the object and its elements? Or perhaps a better approach entirely is needed?

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach is to 1. Ensure the object is immutable, 2. use a separate object to monitor changes:

```
// Records offer immutability, equality and "with"-operator for free
public record ClassA(string Foo, bool Bar);

public class Changeable<T>
{
    private T current;
    public Changeable(T initialValue) => current = initialValue;

    public event EventHandler Changed;
    public T Value {
        get => current;
        set {
            // should probably allow the EqualityComparer to be specified in the constructor
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(current, value)){ 
                current = value;
                Changed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you would monitor changes by attaching an event handler, and do changes by replacing the object:

```
var c = new Changeable2<ClassA>(new ClassA("test", false));
c.Changed += OnChange;
c.Value = c.Value with { Bar = true };
void OnChange(object sender, EventArgs _)
{
    // put your serialization code here.
}
```

One advantage of this is that it does not raise the event if the object is not *actually* changed. It also allow for multiple changes to be done without raising multiple events.

Comment: How can something immutable change? I think the _op_ wants to track changes to writable properties.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou that is the thing, you never change the object, you create a new object and replace the original. This is another style compared to regular objects with mutable properties, but it has some advantages.

Comment: I am aware, and i use this style with struct and records. But the advantage of a class is that you can have multiple references to a single instance, and if you discard this instance due to a change and all the references will go stale. So tread lightly here.

Comment: There are many scenarios where mutability is desirable. For example, if you are collecting input from a user, you want these data elements to be filled in one at a time at the user's pace, and requiring knowing _all_ the properties contents before creating an instance of an object puts an undue burden on the user.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou This pattern isolates the mutability aspects to the `Changeable` object, so you can still share an reference to *that*, with the advantage that each user can also be informed when the object changes. I don't really see how your input example is relevant, you can still create a record with place-holder values, just as you would with a mutable object. Granted, the `with`-syntax is a a bit more complex than setting a property, so that is a tradeoff.

Comment: this is an interesting solution, could you post the executable code too? I seem to have trouble running the snippet you sent.

Comment: @Mathue24 Fixed some bugs in my example. Writing code freehand is difficult. Note that you need a somewhat recent version of C# to be able to use records, local functions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string foo;
    bool bar;

    public A()
    {
        foo = string.Empty;
        bar = false;
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get => foo;
        set
        {
            if (foo != value)
            {
                foo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Foo));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool Bar
    {
        get => bar;
        set
        {
            if (bar != value)
            {
                bar = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bar));
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{foo}:{bar}";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ChangeTracker<T> 
    where T:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ChangeTracker(T target)
    {
        Target = target;
        History = new List<string>();
        History.Add(target.ToString());
        target.PropertyChanged += (s, ev) =>
        {
            History.Add(target.ToString());
        };
    }

    public T Target { get; }
    public List<string> History { get; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        ChangeTracker<A> tracker = new ChangeTracker<A>(a);

        a.Foo = "I am a Fool.";
        a.Bar = true;
        a.Foo = "Fooled ya.";

        foreach (var item in tracker.History)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` provides for a built-in mechanism for tracking property changes by letting observers subscribe to an event when this happens. The event is triggered internally only with `OnPropertyChanged()`

The tracker class just keeps a record of `a.ToString()` *after* each change, as well as the initial value.

The output of the above should be:

```text
:False
I am a Fool.:False
I am a Fool.:True
Fooled ya.:True
```

Comment: seems like a more complex version of @Vadim Martynov's answer. Again, scalability is a bit of an issue, but it seems like the best way to go about it.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the canonical way since it is used by the CLR in windows forms to update the UI when a property is changed.